# Conditional sorting of hits in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I've a index with road names. My settings look like this:

```
  "settings": {
    "max_ngram_diff": 20,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "str_search_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "str_index_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "substring"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "substring": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 255
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the index I've strings like this:

1. Bar Road
2. Bar Foo Road
3. Foo Road

So when I search for 'Foo' I get #2 and #3 as hits. This is expected.

But I would like to control the order of the hits. In this case I would like to have #3 as first hit, because the string starts with the search term.

Is it possible to sort hits as I want?

Answer (score 0):

*The following is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62140698/8160318) answer but has been adapted to your use case.*

```
PUT sorting
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "analyzed": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "str_index_analyzer",
            "search_analyzer": "str_search_analyzer",
            "fielddata": true
          },
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "max_ngram_diff": 20,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "str_search_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "str_index_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "substring"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "substring": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 255
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
GET sorting/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "text.analyzed": "Foo"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
                def docval = doc['text.keyword'].value;
                def length = docval.length();
                def index = (float) docval.indexOf('Foo');

                // the sooner the word appears the better so 'invert' the 'index'
                return index > -1 ? (1 / index) : 0;
              """
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```